# Access files and folders in Jar files

Tags: java

There are many similar questions to this but this is not a duplicate. This is similar to "Can't access files in Jar file" but there is a slight difference. With a lot of experimentation and forum reading, I managed to access the contents of a file and display them from within the Jar file. The problem is that if I were to put the file inside a folder then my program would no longer work even though it works when I run the class file. This is a problem because when I make games and other programs I like having different folders for organisation like "maps" and "spritesheets". I made an experimental program to route out the problem and here is the code for it:

```
        try {
              InputStream is = getClass().getResourceAsStream("folder\\test.txt");
              InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(is);
              BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);
              String line;
              while ((line = br.readLine()) != null)  {
                System.out.println(line);
              }
             br.close();
             isr.close();
             is.close();

       } catch (Exception ex) {}
```

I didn't do anything in the catch section because I had already used it to find the area with the problem. Here is my directory structure:

```
JarFileText
  classes
    com
      sayedhajaj
        folder
          test.txt
        JarFileText.class
        test.txt
   source
     com
       sayedhajaj
         JarFileText.java
```

When I try to access the copy of the text file that is not in the folder, everything works fine. However, if I try to access the copy in "folder", null is returned.

Comment: `catch (Exception ex) {}` -- say it ain't so. And this makes no sense to me: `"I didn't do anything in the catch section because I had already used it to find the area with the problem."`

Comment: Pardon? I don't get what you mean.

Comment: @SayedHajaj       You've got to catch your exceptions and display them...50% of the solution is probably there!

Comment: Oh. I cut that part out.

Comment: I did that and checked but because I kept doing changes in my code such as adding and removing "\\", I found the cause of the problem and found it no longer necessary to have it.

Comment: The separator if `/`, not \. Also, if the JarFileText class is in the package com.sayedhajaj, then the JarFileText.java file should be under source/com/sayedhajaj.

Comment: @SayedHajaj     Do you have full access to the path where you are accessing your "original" contents? Please check your path permissions for the location of 1) copy text file 2) Original text file

Comment: @JBNizet       As long as he escapes using double `\\` it's okay

Comment: What I meant is that I had code in the catch section such as "ex.printStackTrace();" and "System.out.println(getClass().getResourceAsStream("folder\\test.txt")); but I removed it later after I found out that the problem was it was returning null.

Comment: @ha9u63ar no, it's not. Read [the javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ClassLoader.html#getResource%28java.lang.String%29): *The name of a resource is a '/'-separated path name that identifies the resource*

Comment: Does that mean I was supposed to have single "/", most of the posts that I read told me to do the opposite and when using double I was able to access the text folder for the first time but still not the one in the folder.

Comment: What do you think is the most trustworthy? The javadoc, or most of the posts you read?

Comment: Good point. I will try that.

Comment: Wow! It worked it is just "folder/test.txt" with no leading zeros.

Answer (score 2):

This is the solution:

```
        try {
              InputStream is = getClass().getResourceAsStream("folder/test.txt");
              InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(is);
              BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);
              String line;
              while ((line = br.readLine()) != null)  {
                System.out.println(line);
              }
             br.close();
             isr.close();
             is.close();

       } catch (Exception ex) {}
```